# Load comboBox with enum`s - UWP and MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

how can I load a ComboBox with an enum in UWP and using the MVVM model with C #, he searched and can not find

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey

I have brought the process to load a comBox using an enum... A little time I was neciesting it but I did not find it belive it

The first thing is to create the enum that we will need, in a class called "enums" and the enum will be called "TYPE_IDENTITY":

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Proyect.Model
{
    public enum TYPE_IDENTITY: byte {
        [Display (Name = "Nit")] NIT,
        [Display (Name = " Identification Card ")] IC,
        [Display (Name = " Foreign Identification Card ")] FIC,
        [Display (Name = "Passaport")] PASSAPORT,
        [Display (Name = "Other")] OTHER = 9
    }
}
```

Now we will create the ComboBox on the XAML page, in our case the page is called "CombWithEnum.xaml":

```
<ComboBox x: Name = "CobIdenti" Header = "Document Type" Width = "150" />
```

we enter the code behind the "CombWithEnum.xaml.cs" view and add a method, which loads the enums in the comboBox, and in the constructor we call it:

```
public CombWithEnum () // This is the contructor
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.EnumsCombo(); 
}

public void EnumsCombo () // This is the method that will load the ComboBox
{
     var _enumval = Enum.GetValues​​(typeof (Proyect.Model.TYPE_IDENTITY)).Cast<Proyect.Model.TYPE_IDENTITY> ();
     var x = _enumval.ToList();
     CobIdenti.ItemsSource = x;
}
```

Now if we want to omit some item from the enums in the comboBox we add:

```
x.Remove (Proyect.Model.TYPE_IDENTITY.FIC); // In this case I would omit "FIC" when loading the list
```

The method would be like this:

```
public void EnumsCombo ()
{
      var _enumval = Enum.GetValues ​​(typeof (Proyect.Model.TYPE_IDENTITY)).Cast<Proyect.Model.TYPE_IDENTITY> ();
      var x = _enumval.ToList();
      CobIdenti.ItemsSource = x;
}
```

If you want you can Binding the ViewModel if you use MVVM from the ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CobIdenti" Header="Document Type" Width="150" SelectedValue="{Binding Type_Identity_Binding, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In the ViewModel would remain the object, for the use of the class

```
 public class CombWithEnum : ViewModelBase
 {
      public TYPE_IDENTITY Type_Identity_Binding{get; set;}
 }
```

ENJOY!!!!